# Generate Numbers into Alert Box

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a button-press that generates numbers into an alert box. In that alert box I want the numbers to be separated by `< > =`.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getRNG(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  function rollD20()
  {
    var x = document.getElementById("output").value = getRNG(1, 20);
    var y = document.getElementById("output").value = getRNG(1, 20);
    var z = document.getElementById("output").value = getRNG(1, 20);
    if(y == z && y == x && y != null)
        alert(display.output)
  }
</script>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <button onclick="rollD20();">Roll</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this what you're looking for?

```
var x = document.getElementById("output").value = getRNG(1, 20);
var y = document.getElementById("output").value = getRNG(1, 20);
var z = document.getElementById("output").value = getRNG(1, 20);
alert(output(x, y, z));

// e.g. If x = 8, y = 15, z = 3, then output = "x < y > z";
function output(x, y, z) {
    var output = "x "

    if (x < y)
        output += '< y '
    else if (x === y)
        output += '= y ';
    else
        output += '> y ';

    if (y < z)
        output += '< z'
    else if (y === z)
        output += '= z ';
    else
        output += '> z ';

    return output;
}
```

Comment: It served the purpose of what I was trying to accomplish. When the alert box appears it displays x,y,z as opposed to numbers but I'm working to fix that tonight.